# Activeweb java version

Tags: activejdbc, activeweb

does Activeweb really need to be java 1.8?

I'd like to be able to use App Engine's standard edition[1], but it only supports java 1.7.

I'm quite behind on activeweb development, so would appreciate understanding the need for 1.8 at least.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need Java7, there is an ActiveWeb backward-compatible release for Java 7: http://javalite.io/activeweb-release-notes-january-7-2017

The same is available for ActiveJDBC: http://javalite.io/activejdbc-release-notes-january-06-2017

However, with Java 7 was released 6 years ago, and Java 8 is about 3 years old now, I'd suggest to not look back. and just use Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Meh. It looks like java 1.8 is around the corner in standard edition.

Mentioned at bottom of:
https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/03/your-favorite-languages-now-on-Google-App-Engine.html